# Understanding a proof of Wedderburn in Topics in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-ring

I am working on the proof of Wedderburn theorem and I have a problem to understand the part of it.

In Herstein's book, I can't understand the claim "$r$ is a prime number."

I am not clear that "$a^{r_1}$ has an order relative to $Z$ smaller than that of $a$" is a contradiction.

Could anyone explain in detail, please?

[image: Book extract]

Comment: Welcome. I will embed the image for you, as I believe you are unable to as a new user. In the meantime, I suggest you copy out the text yourself into the question, as images are not preferred, and that you use MathJax to render mathematics; one uses dollar signs for this, and sometimes backslashes. Example: `$x\cdot\sin\theta,\exp(z^{2y})$` would render: $x\cdot\sin\theta,\exp(z^{2y})$

Comment: It would also be good to provide a little more context and explanation - what is unclear? Why is their claim confusing? What do you know and what would you say? Etc.

Comment: $a$ is chosen of minimal order, so finding an element $a^{r_1}$ of order  $\le r_2<r$ is surely a contradiction. I don't think I can explain any more clearly than Herstein.

Comment: @WHERE234 I’m glad you had a good welcome. Remember to format with MathJax in the future! You should also accept José’s answer if it helped you, as that will remove the question from the unanswered queue (and it is respectful)

Comment: @WHERE234 Precisely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $r$ is not prime. Then you can write $r$ as $r_1r_2$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are natural numbers greater than $1$. But then $(a^{r_1})^{r_2}=a^r\in Z$. So, if $b=a^{r_1}$, $b^{r_2}\in Z$. But $r_2<r$ and the author was supposing that $r$ is the smallest natural number such that $c^r\in Z$ for some $c\in D\setminus Z$. So, a contradiction is reached. It was a conclusion of the assumption that $r$ is a composite number. So, since $r$ cannot be $1$, it has to be a prime number.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.